# declaring multiple variables in a single statement

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Saw something akin to the following in a js snippet:

```
var aaa = "eeee" + "rrrrr", bbb = "qqqqq" + "tttttt";
```

I'm confused, what is the advantage of doing that vs just:

```
var aaa = "eeee" + "rrrrr";
var bbb = "qqqqq" + "tttttt";
```

Comment: There's no advantage. It's just a personal preference.

Comment: micro-optimization..........

Comment: Regarding your edit: I hope you know what `var` is doing and that there is a difference between using `var` and not using it (i.e. `var aaa = "eeee" + "rrrrr"` and `aaa = "eeee" + "rrrrr";`).

Comment: The title of your post is wrong. It's not a "variable assignment", it's a "variable declaration with initialization".

Comment: And it's not "weird" by any stretch of the imagination, it's fundamental JS syntax, and if anything probably more common than separate `var` statements. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma, in this situation, allows you to declare multiple variables without having to re-use the `var` keyword over and over again:

```
var variable1 = 'foo',
    variable2 = 'bar';
```

Comment: Except that the code snippet that OP mentioned isn't a declaration. It's a definition.

Comment: So this doesn't have anything to do with tuple notation then?

Comment: @red888: There are no tuples in JS, so probably not.

Comment: forgive me I cut and pasted and missed the var I'll fix that

Comment: @red888: You probably have to update your second code snippet as well. Or are you really asking what the difference between using `var` and not using it is? *edit:* apparently not :)

Comment: So the comma is not evaluating anything here its just alternative syntax to a bunch of individual var statements.

Comment: @Fleix Kling: whoops super sloppy sorry about that

Comment: @red888 BTW some JavaScript interpreters do have [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) allowing you to do things like `var { foo, bar } = { foo: 0, bar: 1 }` and `var [foo, bar] = [0, 1]`.